# Java compilation error with BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

For practicing purpose, I am trying to copy and paste a program from a book and find out the result but it still brings me the compilation error: `"cannot find symbol - class ActionListner"`.

My compiler if **BlueJ**.
The code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Ex3
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        F f = new F (" Exemplul 3 ");
        f.setSize(300, 100); f.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class F extends Frame implements ActionListner {
    Label L1, L2; 
    TextField T1, T2; 
    Button B;
    int c1, c2;

    F(String s) {
        setTitle(s); setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        L1 = new Label("Numar"); add(L1);
        T1 = new TextField("0"); add(T1);
        L2 = new Label("Plus "); add(L2);
        T2 = new TextField("0"); add(T2);

        B = new Button("Adauga"); add(B);
        B.addActionListner(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        c2 = Integer.parseInt (T2.getText());
        c1 += c2; T1.seText(Integer.toString(c1));
    }
}
```

Can anyone give any clue about the error, please?
BTW: please note that this is my 1st Java code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is `ActionListener`, not `ActionListner`.  Use a proper IDE

Comment: When you say `import java.awt.event.*;` there is no need for the next two imports , try reading about Packages in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo. The class is called `ActionListener`, not `ActionListner`